# If i pay a creditor directly can a collector still sue for fees?

Tags: debt, debt-collection

We paid a creditor the full amount that was owed plus interest.  The collector is charging $9000 on a $13000 debt. We feel this is exorbitant. Can we still be sued by the collector?

Comment: Depends on your contract and local law. You could try specifying your location, but odds are we can't help you. Have a lawyer look at the paperwork, then decide whether arguing about it is likely to cost you more than the fee even if you win.

Comment: The question is, who actually owns the debt? If the original creditor, the collector should have no standing: they were just working for the creditor. If the collector *bought* the debt, the original creditor should not have taken your money, as the debt was no longer theirs to collect. This is what you need to ascertain.

Answer (score -2):

In the US, the answer is undoubtedly yes. In fact *I* could sue you over the debt and I don't even know you.  There really are no practical barriers to anyone suing anyone else.

Whether they could win? That is up to the court.

Comment: Actually in the US you'll need to know *who* the person you're suing *is* and have them served, before the court would even entertain your case. So there's *a* barrier...

Comment: A technically correct but completely unhelpful answer.